# How do I update my iOS app's content with background downloading?

Tags: ios, json, swift, background

TL;DR: I want to add images to the app over the internet through background downloading of some sort, but don't know where to start, or what the best method is.

My app displays images to the users which can be filtered etc. I have a "Cards" class that has fields for name, image, etc. I then have a huge area directly in my code where I create instances of the Cards class for each image. There is then an array of these class instances, which helps with displaying them.

My issue is that now I want to be able to update this block of class instances without having to push another build to the iTunes store. Essentially, I want to add "Cards" to the app (images with appropriate names and keywords associated with them). I need to be able to update the app every month (sometimes less) with new cards as quickly as possible.

I have heard suggestions here and there about JSON files and background downloading, but can't figure out which method I need for my situation.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Your question looks a little too broad and there are literally hundreds of tutorials about iOS apps comunicating with backend. If you haven't done this before, just read a few and pick one that looks most promising to you. Then, if you have a more specific problem, everyone will be glad to help you with it.

Comment: @Losiowaty Thanks for the constructive criticism! Most people down vote without saying a word. I tried reading around, but couldn't tell which ones were really relevant to my situation. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction after hearing my situation, but if not I'll keep digging.

Comment: No problem, everyone was once in your situation :) To give you a starting point : https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2

Comment: Just look at few tutorials and you will get it. You can always ask for help.

Comment: @Trevor Jordy - what i am getting is you need a method to download your content in background thread ? If yes then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you just want to update your app content in future without uploading a new build to App Store. Right ?

If you want to do so, make your app so flexible that you can show updated contents in your app.

Here is a short instruction which you can follow...

1. Develop an admin panel if you are aware of any backend scripting language like php. And you can add contents from this panel into your database.
2. Create an API which will fetch the content from your database
3. Make your app flexible so that it can show all the updated content getting from the API. If you have a list of content then you can use TableView/CollectionView with pagination.

If you still face any problem then let me know. I will see deep into your problem.